# Orchard Custom Module - Model being picked up by NHibernate - Requiring virtual properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, orchardcms

I'm working on building a custom module in Orchard CMS, and I have the following Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Inventory()
{
   var models = _repository.Get<MyModel>();
   return View(new MyViewModel() { MyModels = models.ToList() });
}
```

Now, when Orchard builds this, an exception occurs, because NHibernate has picked up MyModel because its being looked at as a PartRecord, which I do not want it to be.

The exception is method get_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'.

I can add virtual to the properties, but I want to avoid having NHibernate have any part in looking at this object, it is unnecessary.

My question is, how can I add a Model, access that model in a view and suppress Orchard from treating it as a PartRecord?  I actually use the model in a separate repository, separate from the Orchard DB.

EDIT: Additional Information

_repository is an IDbRepository, pointing to my own DB instance
MyModel is a POCO for my data.  I'm trying avoid putting virtual on the properties in MyModel, I have them in here, to illustrate where I'm trying to avoid them.

```
public interface IDbRepository : IDependency
{
    T Find<T>(long id) where T : class, IActiveRecord;
    bool Update<T>(T record) where T : class, IActiveRecord;
    bool Remove<T>(T record) where T : class, IActiveRecord;
}

public class MyModel : IActiveRecord
{
    [Key]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int SupplierProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

In addition to this, my module does have a settings part that I've created, that does get stored in Orchard DB and is edited in the site settings.  I'm using a handler to control that.  However, I've tried removing the handler and a few other things to keep Orchard from taking my object into NHibernate.

Comment: What's _repository here? And what does MyModel look like?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I have edited my solution above to answer your questions, thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Orchard auto-mapping configuration assumes that any class will be mapped if the following conditions are met:

- the namespace ends with ".Models" or ".Records"
- there is an `Id` property, with virtual accessors
- the class is neither sealed nor abstract
- the class doesn't implement `IContent` or inherits from `ContentPartRecord`

So if you prevent any of those criteria from being true, you should be good. For instance, defining your classes in a namespace not ending with `.Models` or `.Records` should be sufficient.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I moved it out of the models .Models namespace and that did it. Also, good thorough answer taught me a lot.  Thank you.