# Orchard data insert/delete for non content item

Tags: orchardcms

I am intending to insert/delete some information in a module's Action (using Orchard Rules-Action API) in a one-column table in the database. What is the best way of doing such tasks i.e. Data manipulation of non-content items. I do not want to go by the "Create a content type" route. I simply want to persist some non-content data in the database and query/delete them.

```
namespace xyz.Models
{
    public class Task
    {
        public virtual int ContentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int Retries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Task",
                     table => table
                         .Column<int>("ContentId")
                         .Column<int>("Retries")                     
                     ); 


                return 1;
```

---

```
namespace Xyz.Services
{
    public class TaskService : ITaskService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Task> _taskRepository;

        public TaskService(IRepository<Task> taskRepository)
        {
            _taskRepository = taskRepository;
        }

        public Task CreateTask(int contentId)
        {
            var task = new Task { ContentId = contentId };
            _taskRepository.Create(task);
            return task;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use Orchards content stuff, you can just create an MVC project that will sit inside Orchard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "creating a table without `ContentPart`" by non-content, then just create your desired model in the models folder :

```
  public class MyRecord{

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string FOO{ get; set; }

        public virtual string BAR{ get; set; }

    }
```

and obviously you must create a table in migration as following :

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MyRecord",
                table => table
                    .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                    .Column<string>("FOO")
                    .Column<string>("BAR")
                );
```

and finally where you want to have a transaction over table ,simply inject an instance of your model's `repository` :

```
private readonly IRepository<MyRecord> _repository;

public SomeClass(IRepository<MyRecord> repository){
    _repository = repository;    
}


  public SomeMethod(){
        var record = new MyRecord();
        //initialize your class here
      _repository.Create(record);
  }
```

**Important** to note is that your record class must be in the Models folder and must contain an Id property.

Comment: I was also thinking along the same lines. I tried the above approach. I am getting this nhibernate mapping error - No persister for: <Module_Name>.Models.MyRecord. Note the name of the table created is <Prefix>_<ModuleName>_MyRecord while the fully qualified name of the model class is <ModuleName>.Models.MyRecord. I am not sure how to tell Orchard the mapping between the model class and corresponding table. I have followed the convention of tablename=classname and columnname=propertyname. Still its not working. Is it because I am using a prefix with Orchard tables ??

Comment: i suspect that you have referenced wrong Class.there is another class called `Task` in orchard core.check and make sure you are referencing your own `Task` class.

Comment: I was referencing the right class. Just to double check I renamed the class from Task to TaskB and did the same for table. Still the same result. "No persister for TaskB"

Comment: @Subhasis just found a link regarding your problem.check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840250/orchard-custom-module-model-being-picked-up-by-nhibernate-requiring-virtual - i think the second one (refereed in preceding link) is your case.

Comment: Bull's eye. Orchard needs Id column. Marking this thread as answer. Thanks a ton for sticking to the problem and helping me resolve this.